# Use Gmail with purchased domain for free?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I used to use the free version of Google Apps to handle a domain's emails (but not hosting the website) so my clients could use the Gmail interface for emails and get some free storage. It seems, however, this service is no longer free. Is there another free way to do the same thing or similar?

I’ve found [this link](http://thumbakanijuan.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/set-your-domain-name-as-your.html) but it’s not exactly what I want. This method forwards emails to a Gmail account and then you can change the `from` address in Gmail. However, I’ve heard that some email clients will show the actual Gmail address, not the one you've set instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you were using Google Apps for free before they removed their free offering, you will be able to continue using it for free. Only newly registered domains won't be able to opt for the free trail version any longer.

I'm curious myself whether these domains will be able to have the free version forever or whether Google will start to charge them as well in the future.

When trying to setup e-mail for a new domain, you could consider [Outlook.com](http://Outlook.com), the new cloud service from Microsoft. Yahoo has a [similar service](http://smallbusiness.yahoo.com/email/compare-plans) as well. You could also take a look at GoDaddy's [e-mail hosting offering](http://www.godaddy.com/email/email-hosting.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you are only in need of one account, then you can still use Google Apps through this [workaround](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-appengine/pVZfdeky-ow/TO1SmipM2Y0J). The limitation is that you can only have one email account.

Another free alternative would be [Zoho mail](http://www.zoho.com/mail/zohomail-pricing.html) which allows 5 users at maximum.
Zoho Mail offers POP/ IMAP and Active Sync options to access your email. They have a cool mobile interface (m.zoho.com)