# Is it possible to host in the cloud but have email in Gmail?

Tags: domain, dns, amazon-ec2

Is it possible to host a website for example in Amazon Cloud and have my domain point there, but have the same domain installed with Gmail for mail support?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! The short answer is Yes, but the long answer depends on whether you're doing one email address or multiple, and if you want free or paid Gmail. This is covered in a previous question, which I'll just link you to instead of reiterating all the details. http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/37123/use-gmail-with-purchased-domain-for-free

Answer (score 2):

As Eisb said in the comment the short answer is yes. For more detail keep reading.

Assuming you want to (or already) use the Google Apps email service you can point your [MX records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record) in your DNS configuration panel to Google servers, BUT your naked domain or WWW sub-domain to wherever you are hosting your webpage. To accomplish this you must have access to your domain configuration panel available in your [Domain Name Registrar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name_registrar) (Go Daddy or the like).

Suggested reading (wikipedia a good and easy to understand source):

- DNS - Domain Name System
- Domain Name
- Resource Record

Plus the Google Apps forums and tutorials.

google apps: www.google.com/a/

Comment: Why did someone downvote this correct answer?